Chargebee TypeError: Failed to create subscription chargebee
When I'm trying to make request with Chargebee I'm getting an error

Error: Failed to create subscription

async createSubscriptionForTeamMember(customerId, options) {
    try {
        // Proceed with subscription creation using Chargebee API
        console.log(customerId); // 16CMrdUBRD3oj1Wy5
        console.log(options); // {subscription_items: [ { item_price_id: 'monthly', quantity: 1 } ]}
        const subscriptionResult = await chargebee.subscription.create_with_items(customerId, options).request();
        const subscription = subscriptionResult.subscription;

        console.log('subscription', subscription.status);

        // Retrieve customer information including payment method
        const customerResult = await chargebee.customer.retrieve(customerId).request();
        const customer = customerResult.customer;

        console.log('customer.payment_method', customer.id);

        // Parse subscription details
        const nextBillingTimestamp = parseInt(subscription.next_billing_at) * 1000;
        const nextBilling = new Date(nextBillingTimestamp);
        const billingInterval = subscription.billing_period_unit === 'year' ? 'annual' : 'monthly';

        // Return subscription details
        return {
            nextBilling,
            subscriptionStatus: subscription.status,
            customerId: customer.id,
            subscriptionId: subscription.id,
            billingInterval
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating subscription:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to create subscription');
    }
}


I've encountered an issue with my code that involves creating subscriptions with Chargebee. The code was previously working fine for over two years without any problems, but suddenly it stopped working today. The error seems to be related to the following line:
const subscriptionResult = await chargebee.subscription.create_with_items(customerId, options).request();


The 'customerId' and 'options' variables are correctly populated with valid data before this line is executed.
There have been no recent changes to this part of the code or the environment that could explain this sudden issue.
The code has been working reliably for more than two years.
Now, on sometimes, the code executes successfully, while on other days, it fails with an error at the line mentioned above.
The failure seems to be random and does not consistently occur under specific conditions.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on what could be causing this issue or how to troubleshoot it further. If anyone has experienced a similar problem or has ideas on how to resolve this, please let me know.
Thank you in advance for your help!

You are trying to add a subscription to an account that has no payment method linked to it, all while your Chargebee's Auto Collection is ON.
Testing Environnment
You can use Test Cards e.g. 4111 1111 1111 1111.
Documentation:

Chargebee Test Gateway

Chargebee Test Card Numbers


Production Environnment
You have to check correctly if the account has a payment method before trying to charge it, if not, stop the function and show the client a message that they have no payment method.
In the case where your business use case is to take payments out of Chargebee, then you should turn Auto Collection OFF
Source from Chargebee

Right now, I'm testing and I don't want to make changes directly on the Chargebee website. I'm looking for a solution within my code.

@OmarChakroun The fact that you're testing should have been put in the question.
I updated my answer.
